# How to print excel column non null value with python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following excel sheet:[image]

and want to print column 1 value if the column 2 value is not null. The output should be [1,3].

This the script created by me, but it doesn't work:

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

filename='test.xlsx'
dataframe = pd.read_excel(filename)
frame = dataframe.loc[dataframe["col2"] !=" "]
df =  frame.iloc[:, 0]

ndarray = df.to_numpy()
print(ndarray)
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: you try to filter for a whitespace: `" "` this is propably the problem. in empty "cells" pandas uses numpy.nan, so its easier to uses pandas built in functionality to filter for those rows, like with .notna()

Comment: The result is [1,2,3,4] but expected output is [1,3]

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. It worked afer change it to : frame = dataframe.loc[dataframe["col2"].notna()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter down to nona rows and then show the values of the column you want to show:

```
dataframe[df['col2'].notna()]['col1'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the dataframe, you will see that the empty cells are `NaN`:

```
      Col1 Col2
 0     1    a
 1     2  NaN
 2     3    b
 3     4  NaN
```

So, you need to use the `notna()` method to filter

Here is your fixed code:

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

filename='test.xlsx'
dataframe = pd.read_excel(filename)
frame = dataframe.loc[dataframe["col2"].notna()]
df =  frame.iloc[:, 0]

ndarray = df.to_numpy()
print(ndarray)
```